# Multiple unidirectional oneToMany relationship columns from one table to another table in JPA

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to have a localization table that is linked to from multiple tables. 
I'm realizing that the problem is that I'm using the ID of Localization (eg Localization_Id) so I can't link to different localizations without some other key. Should I use a join table or some other sequential id in the database somehow? Not sure what the best approach is using JPA.

Thanks in advance.

```
@Entity
public class MyEntityWithLocalization {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="LOCALIZATION_KEY")
    List<Localization> field1;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="LOCALIZATION_KEY")
    List<Localization> field2; //can't be unique from field one as it links to the MyEntityWithLocalization id.

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="LOCALIZATION_KEY")
    List<Localization> field3; //can't be unique from field one as it links to the MyEntityWithLocalization id.

}

@Entity
public class Localization {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    long id;

    String language;
    String string;

    public Localization(String language, String string) {
        this.language = language;
        this.string = string;
    }

    public Localization(){

    }
}
```

This creates a localization_key in the localization table but that is just keyed to the ID of the MyEntityWithLocalization - it needs to be another unique value which makes me believe a join table may make sense in this case.

```
create table localization (
    id number(19,0) not null,
    language varchar2(255),
    string varchar2(255),
    localization_key number(19,0),
    primary key (id)
);
```

Comment: In your model (let's ignore JPA for a second), what is the difference between the three fields?

Comment: They would represent three fields. Say name, description, image location where each need a localization.

Comment: AFAIK you will not be able to map this relationship using standard JPA, as you will need to add extra *constant* criteria for each localization entry (the localization_key). Do you use Hibernate?

Comment: For now I'm just going to strip it down to a 1 to 1 and have the localizations as column names - there are only 2 localizations. It's less ideal but it makes the solution much simpler. Yes I'm using hibernate but wanted to use JPA to have less coupling to the engine.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Why not just split the entity into constant and localizable part? Something like this:

```
@Entity
class MyEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    long id;

    @OneToMany
    @MapKeyColumn
    Map<String, MyEntityLocalization> localizations;
}

@Embeddable
class MyEntityLocalization {
    String field1;

    String field2;

    String field3;
}
```

Where the localizations field has the map from the language to the localization? The other way is using Hibernate-specific annotations:

```
@Entity
class MyEntityWithLocalization {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    long id;

    @OneToMany
    @MapKeyColumn(name="language")
    @WhereJoinTable(clause = "key=1")
    Map<String, String> field1;

    @OneToMany
    @MapKeyColumn(name="language")
    @WhereJoinTable(clause = "key=2")
    Map<String, String> field2;
}


@Entity
public class Localization {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    long id;

    long key;
    String language;
    String string;
}
```